# How to generate a random string and assign it a value

Tags: java, arrays

I am making a program that has 50 questions in it,so you type the question in text field and click the button. If the question is there in the directory, then a popup will display the answer. Now i want to add a button, on which if the user clicks, the person would be able to add his question and answer in it. Adding the question is easy but I cant figure out, how to add the answer. Here's my program

```
 class te extends JFrame implements ActionListener,MouseListener,KeyListener {
   JButton bnt1;

   JTextField tf;

   JLabel title;

   JLabel q1;

   JLabel ans1;

   JLabel q1f=new JLabel("Question displayed on jframe");

   JButton bnt2;

   JButton b;

   JLabel q2;

   JLabel q3;

  JButton bnt3;

  JButton bnt4;

  JLabel q4;

  JButton bnt5;

  JLabel q5;

  JLabel link;

  ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();

  private JButton bu;

  JTextField tfu;

  JTextField tfu2;

  JButton help;

  String s;

  String ss;

      public te() throws Exception {
       super("IskcoWare");

       this.setUndecorated(true);
       this.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
       tf=new JTextField();



       String s;

       bnt4=new JButton("Ask");

       bnt5=new JButton("Ask");


       bnt3=new JButton("Ask");

       title=new JLabel("50 Glorious Years Of Iskcon");
       title.setFont(new Font("",Font.BOLD+Font.ITALIC,70));

      q1.setFont(new Font("",Font.BOLD,25));

      bnt1=new JButton("Ask");
      bnt1.addActionListener(this);

      b=new JButton("Search");
      b.setBounds(700,170,150,40);
      b.setFont(new Font("",Font.PLAIN,15));
      b.setVisible(true);
      add(b);

      link=new JLabel("<html><a href=\"Something.java\">Click to add your      own question</a>");

      bnt2=new JButton("Ask");

      help=new JButton("Help");

      add(help);

      help.setBounds(100,710,100,40);

      setLayout(null);

      tf.setBounds(150,170,450,30);  
      tf.setForeground(Color.GRAY);

      title.setBounds(190,-150,10000,400);

      q1.setBounds(100,250, 10000, 100);

      bnt1.setBounds(1000,288,70,35);
      bnt1.setFont(new Font("",Font.PLAIN,17));

      bnt2.setFont(new Font("",Font.PLAIN,17));
      bnt2.setBounds(1000,370, 70,35);

      q2.setBounds(100,180,400,400);
      q2.setFont(new Font("",Font.BOLD,25));

      q3.setBounds(100,270,400,400);
      q3.setFont(new Font("",Font.BOLD,25));

       bnt3.setBounds(1000,460,70,35);
       bnt3.setFont(new Font("",Font.PLAIN,17));

       bnt4.setBounds(1000,550,70,35);
       bnt4.setFont(new Font("",Font.PLAIN,17));

       q4.setBounds(100,360,400,400);
       q4.setFont(new Font("",Font.BOLD,25));

       q5.setBounds(100,450,500,400);
       q5.setFont(new Font("",Font.BOLD,25));

       bnt5.setBounds(1000,640,70,35);
       bnt5.setFont(new Font("",Font.PLAIN,17));

       link.setBounds(1000,550,400,400);
       link.setFont(new Font("",Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC,15));;

        add(link);

        add(tf);

         add(title); 

         add(q1);

         add(bnt1);

         add(tf);

         add(b);

         add(bnt3);

         add(q3);

         add(bnt2);

         add(bnt4);

         add(q4);

         add(bnt5);

         add(q5);

         bnt5.addActionListener(this);
         bnt2.addActionListener(this);
         bnt3.addActionListener(this);
         bnt4.addActionListener(this);


          add(q2);

           setSize(10000,730);

           setVisible(true);

           link.addMouseListener(this);


           UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());

            Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();

            items.add("Questions");
            tf.addMouseListener(this);
            tf.setSize(400,37);
            tf.addKeyListener(this);
            tf.setFont(new Font("",Font.PLAIN,25));
            b.addActionListener(new loginButt(tf));
            b.addActionListener(this);
            setupAutoComplete(tf, items);
            help.addActionListener(this);
            tf.setColumns(30);
            tf.setText("hello");
}
        private static boolean isAdjusting(JComboBox cbInput) {
    cbInput.setFont(new Font("",Font.PLAIN,20));
    new JScrollPane(null,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

     if (cbInput.getClientProperty("is_adjusting") instanceof Boolean) {
        return (Boolean) cbInput.getClientProperty("is_adjusting");
    }
    return false;
}

    public JScrollPane createScroller()
    {
        return new JScrollPane(null,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    }

private static void setAdjusting(JComboBox cbInput, boolean adjusting) {
    cbInput.putClientProperty("is_adjusting", adjusting);
}

public static void setupAutoComplete(final JTextField tf, final ArrayList<String> items) {
    final DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
    final JComboBox cbInput = new JComboBox(model)
   //


    {

        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(super.getPreferredSize().width, 0);
        }
    };
    setAdjusting(cbInput, false);
    for (String item : items) {
        model.addElement(item);
    }
    cbInput.setSelectedItem(null);
    cbInput.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (!isAdjusting(cbInput)) {
                if (cbInput.getSelectedItem() != null) {
                    tf.setText(cbInput.getSelectedItem().toString());
                }
            }
        }
    });

    tf.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            setAdjusting(cbInput, true);
           //bla
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                e.setSource(cbInput);
                cbInput.dispatchEvent(e);
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                    tf.setText(cbInput.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    cbInput.setPopupVisible(false);
                }
            }
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
                cbInput.setPopupVisible(false);
            }
            setAdjusting(cbInput, false);
        }
    });
    tf.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            updateList();
        }

        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            updateList();
        }

        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            updateList();
        }

        private void updateList() {
            setAdjusting(cbInput, true);
            model.removeAllElements();
            String input = tf.getText();
            if (!input.isEmpty()) {
                for (String item : items) {
                    if (item.toLowerCase().startsWith(input.toLowerCase())) {
                        model.addElement(item);
                    }
                }
            }
            cbInput.setPopupVisible(model.getSize() > 0);
            setAdjusting(cbInput, false);
        }
    });
    tf.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    tf.add(cbInput, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
 }
```

This is the the other class

```
public class SubmitButton{
JTextField Input;
String s;

public SubmitButton(JTextField textfield){
    Input = textfield;
}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

   String q1 = "questions";


               if(Input.getText().equals(q1))
               {
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The answer",     "Answer",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
         }
```

Comment: What specifically are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1):

Simplify your problem.

You don't need all that Swing code to solve your sub-problem.

Try it with a command line interface on a simple version of the problem, then fold that into your bigger code base.

Computer science is about decomposition.  Solve large problems by breaking them into smaller ones.

It sounds like you want to generate a Random number in the range of the length of a List of questions.  Generate an index and pull the question.